# Undefined index in $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"

Tags: php, html

I have code with php, when I run then display an error message

PHP Notice: Undefined index: esn /var/www/html/sat line 10

PHP Notice: Undefined index: lat /var/www/html/sat line 11

PHP Notice: Undefined index: lon /var/www/html/sat line 12

PHP Notice: Undefined index: status /var/www/html/sat line 13

Each made the call `http://domains.com/sat/index.php?esn=value1&lat=value2&lon=value3&status=value4` and the results of calling these parameters are always "NULL".

We may be given a solution to this case. Thanks

below this source code error:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
    {
      $postText=file_get_contents('php://input');
      //collect value of input field
      $esn = $_POST['esn'];
      $lat = $_POST['lat'];
      $lon = $_POST['lon'];
      $status = $_POST['status'];
      fwrite($postText);
      fclose($FileHandle);

      if ($postText) 
      {
         echo "Nomor ESN: ".$esn."<br>";
         echo "Latitude: ".$lat."<br>";
         echo "Longitude: ".$lon."<br>";
         echo "status: ".$status."<br>";
      }else{
         echo "NULL";
      }    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use GET method while you access data using Post method. so you getting variable is null.
Use bellow code for GET method

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") 
    {
      $postText=file_get_contents('php://input');
      //collect value of input field
      $esn = $_GET['esn'];
      $lat = $_GET['lat'];
      $lon = $_GET['lon'];
      $status = $_GET['status'];
      fwrite($postText);
      fclose($FileHandle);

      if ($postText) 
      {
         echo "Nomor ESN: ".$esn."<br>";
         echo "Latitude: ".$lat."<br>";
         echo "Longitude: ".$lon."<br>";
         echo "status: ".$status."<br>";
      }else{
         echo "NULL";
      }    
    }
```

Comment: His data are never in $_POST so it will not resolve the main problem

Comment: Hi vishal Khunt, Thanks for expert responses.

Answer (score 1):

Your data, even if you send them by form, right now are in URL so they are in $_GET not in $_POST array